# Carousel not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to run a carousel but it isn't working. I do not know where it went wrong. I got the navbar section to work, for some reason the carousel doesn't show up at all. Am I supposed to put the carousel above the navbar, or is it fine the way I have it now? Am I supposed to put the carousel inside a container div? Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Paints &amp; Prints</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pp">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Paints &amp; Prints</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="pp">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Your Account
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="list-box">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide1.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Skilled Artists</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide2.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Made with the Finest Paints</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide3.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>See us at Street Art Events</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any console errors in browser?

Comment: You have not initialized the carousel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you call carousel in your JS file?
$('.carousel').carousel();

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-4

Comment: I did that, I got it to run. Thanks though, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Check this, it may help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Paints &amp; Prints</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pp">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Paints &amp; Prints</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="pp">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Your Account
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="list-box">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="" alt="s"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
         Skilled Artists
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src=""/>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          Made with the Finest Paints
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src=""/>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
         See us at Street Art Events
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
  </div>

  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I got it solved, I forgot to add a css snippet code to make it work. Thanks though